# Why is the resultSet.getInt (1); necessary in the following code?

Tags: java, jdbc, count

As far as I know `getInt(column index)`retrieves a column value from the current row, but I don't understand its purpose in a situation like this. Doesn't the SQL statement `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Gyujtoallomasok`
already count the rows in the table? If so, why do we need the rest?

```
public int count() {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Gyujtoallomasok");
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            int count = resultSet.getInt(1);
            return count;
        }
    } catch (SQLException exception) {
        // TODO: log
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove it? (Meant as a pedagogical question: if you think something is unnecessary, you must think something happens without it)

Comment: `COUNT(*)` will create column in ResultSet with type `int` for no of rows. You are reading values from integer type column thats why `resultSet.getInt(1)` you are using this statement. Refer documentation for more clearence [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `executeQuery()` returns a `ResultSet` object and not an integer value.
The statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Gyujtoallomasok
```

*counts the rows in the table* and returns this result in the *unnamed* column `COUNT(*)`.
To get this result you must extract it from the `ResultSet` object with the method `getInt()`, since the result is an integer, by passing the index `1` of the column (it is the 1st and only column in the `ResultSet`):

```
resultSet.getInt(1)
```

If you aliased the column like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter FROM Gyujtoallomasok
```

you could also get its value with:

```
resultSet.getInt("counter")
```

Answer (score 3):

`getInt` is still needed since this line:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Gyujtoallomasok");
```

is placing what is returned from the database into a [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) which is *"A table of data representing a database result set"*.

You then must iterate through the ResultSet to retrieve your answer which is what `resultSet.next()` and `resultSet.getInt();` are doing.